# CRS.decode gets stuck (deadlock)

Tags: java, geotools

I am trying to execute following code `CRS.decode(EPSG:4326, true)` and execution just stops, no errors, no exceptions, nothing.

I am using `org.geotools:gt-referencing:26.5`. Any ideas what I could try, or what could be the issue ?

Comment: Time to debug. Put breakpoint on the decode method an step through until you reach the line that halts the application. Is CPU going up? Then it's probably a loop that does not terminate.

Comment: Or take a thread dump with `jstack` or `kill -3`

Comment: What else are you depending on? that code isn't normally threaded so I doubt it is a deadlock - does your user have write permission to the temp directory?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce it locally, only on this server, so I am not sure, can I do a thread dump there somehow ? We have entire org.geotools dependency, but I have tracked it down with log messages and it for sure just stops on CRS.decode

Comment: Then it is almost certainly a write permission issue with exploding the projections directory.

Comment: Where can this permissions be configured ? I am not aware of them

Comment: One additional thing I did notice is that this fails randomly, it would pass maybe once every 100 tries